# How to solve displayed emulator in connected devices android studio more than one

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

I want to ask to you about how to detect emulator in Android Studio especially in version 3.1. I have problem that when I run Nox Emulator and MEMU together, the connected devices list shows only one that has displayed in dialog when I click run in Android Studio. I also restarted Android Studio and both emulators and the result is the same.

How can I display both emulators in the connected devices list dialog? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It should appear without any further customizations. I have used Nox Emulator for a while and you have to do a little trick to make it work for debugging:

1. Click the `debug` or `run` button on Android Studio
2. Wait for the popup to open (the one where it lists the connected devices)
3. Run Nox Emulator
4. After Nox is ready and running, it should appear on your connected devices list.

Comment: yes, if i run emulator only nox, it is successfull. but i ask how do i displayed emulator more than one when the nox and memu run together? sorry my english is bad :( thank you in advance

Comment: Do you really need different emulators? You could try with Nox Multi-Drive where you could run multiple instances of Nox Emulator. I'm not familiar with MEMU, sorry.

Comment: yes i need different emulators. because in nox api android is 19, while in memu api android is 21.

Comment: And when you setup MEMU alone, can you run your app on it?

Comment: yes it is success when i run single emulator. but this case is when i run emulator nox and memu only memu is detected in run dialog android studio and vice versa